# CameraDevice.SetFlash() is not working on android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm using Unity 2022.2.7 and Vuforia Engine v10.14.4. For testing I use a Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G NE with Android version 12. Here is the code I use:

```
public void ToggleFlashLight()
    {
        if(isFlashLightOn)
        {
            isFlashLightOn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isFlashLightOn = true;
        }
        bool wasFlashLisgtActivated = VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFlash(isFlashLightOn);
        Debug.Log("flashlight is on: " + wasFlashLisgtActivated);
    }
```

I call the `ToggleFlashLight()` function from a button. But it doesn't turn on the flashlight. The output in Android logcat when I press the button is "flashlight is on: False" and "Failed to set camera flash mode". Vuforia is initialized when I call this function, and the camera is already working, so that's not the problem.

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.unity3d.player" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="26"
        android:targetSdkVersion="32" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application android:extractNativeLibs="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window"
            android:value="False" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="notch.config"
            android:value="portrait|landscape" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="notch_support"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.exact_scheduling"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="optional" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia Engine on Android uses ARCore which has full control of the native camera. Unfortunately ARCore API does not expose Flash controls (see the discussion here https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/153). This is why the Engine Flash API does not work.

It is possible for Vuforia to use the native camera directly without ARCore by setting a different Fusion Provider (https://library.vuforia.com/environments/vuforia-fusion#fusion-apis). This is likely to fix the flash controls. However it comes at a price: some engine features (e.g., Device Tracker) need ARCore to function properly (see https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recommended-devices).

Answer (score 0):

I found a very stupid solution to this problem
For everyone who ends up here

```
public Toggle toggle;
private void Update()
{ 
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFlash(toggle.isOn);
}
```

I realized that while running the app, the flashlight couldn't be turned on. And while having the flashlight on and starting the app, the app turns it off instantly. So using an update function is my last resort to fix this issue since 2018.

Don't know why the developer decided to turn off the flashlight support.