# Flash Light not working in OnePlus during AR Session

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have developed AR application which include Flash Light functionality. This application runs as expected in Mobile 1(Vivo T1 5G) but flashlight not working in Mobile 2 (OnePlus Nord 2). Both mobile are Android Version 13.

why this application flash light is not working in Mobile 2.?

for this I used below line of code

VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFlash(true);

I'm expecting this why not working in oneplus mobile, need a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CameraDevice.SetFlash() is not working on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084578/cameradevice-setflash-is-not-working-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is the same problem as here [CameraDevice.SetFlash() is not working on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084578/cameradevice-setflash-is-not-working-on-android/76090107#76090107) . The Vivo T1 does not support ARCore (see here https://developers.google.com/ar/devices) so it defaults automatically to Camera2 API which has flashlight control. The OnePlus Nord 2 supports ARCore which is used by default and does not support flashlight control.

Setting the `FusionProvider` to `VUFORIA_FUSION_ONLY` should fix your problem https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/namespaceVuforia.html#a247a4d24f56f9b41c42bbf8c78c8a554 . This is ok as long as the Vuforia features you are using do not need ARCore to function properly (probably not the case as you seem satisfied with the experience on the Vivo T1).

Answer (score 0):

I found a very stupid solution to this problem with Vuforia
For everyone who ends up here

```
public Toggle toggle;
private void Update()
{ 
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFlash(toggle.isOn);
}
```

I realized that while running the app, the flashlight couldn't be turned on. And while having the flashlight on and starting the app, the app turns it off instantly. So using an update function is my last resort to fix this issue since 2018.

Don't know why the developer decided to turn off the flashlight support.